# How to animate SVG rect to fill from bottom to top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I'm working on an SVG here I want blue color fill from bottom to top I had tried using `transform="rotate(-90)"` but the problem is text also rotates. I newbie in an SVG can anyone suggest to me how to achieve this output. Any help will be appreciated!

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

rect {
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="25" oninput="document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('height',this.value+'%')" />

<svg id="SVGslider1" viewBox="0 0 28 6">
  <rect width="100%" height="25%" fill="blue" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  <text x="5" y="5"  font-size="6" fill="green">text here</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer would be to update your CSS with `rect {transform: transform: rotate(180deg); transform-origin: center center;}` to rotate it 180º, pinned to the SVG center.

Alternatively, rebuild the SVG with a white rect overlaid on blue and the slider javascript targets the white rectangle.

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

rect {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="25" oninput="document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('height',this.value+'%')" />

<svg id="SVGslider1" viewBox="0 0 28 6">
  <rect width="100%" height="25%" fill="blue" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  <text x="5" y="5"  font-size="6" fill="green">text here</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of animating the `width` you can animate the `height` and to make it fill from bottom to top you can rotate the `rect` upside around its center:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
}

rect {
  transition: height 0.5s;
  transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="25" value="25" oninput="document.querySelector(`#SVG${this.id} rect`).setAttribute('height',this.value+'%')" />

<svg id="SVGslider1" viewBox="0 0 28 6">
  <rect width="100%" height="25%" fill="blue" transform="rotate(180)" />
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
  <text x="5" y="5"  font-size="6" fill="green">text here</text>
</svg>
```